Restful Standard on PATCH API that contains business logic and addition workflows
I have an api to create an order POST /api/order and to retrieve the order GET /api/order/{order_id}.
I also have a PATCH method to partially update an order PATCH /api/order/{order_id}.
Upon a patch if the user updates the order_status to "Built" I would like to perform some additional logic. For example, send out an email, create a record in another table with the built entity and so forth.
My question is, what is the restful standard in addressing this situation. Should I create a new API to perform this action? Something like POST /api/order/{order_id}/build which updates the order object with order_status of "Built" and then performs the addition workflows? Or should my patch handle the updating of the status and an additional API call made to perform the remaining actions?

Recommendation: review Webber 2011.


My question is, what is the restful standard in addressing this situation.

No, because we really don't need one.
HTTP requests are of the transfer-of-documents-over-a-network domain; they have the semantics of fetching or manipulating your resource model.  How your implementation goes about doing that is your own business.
In other words, useful work is a side effect of the handling of the request to manipulate the resource.
So if you want to kick off a bunch of business processes because someone sent you a patch document that describes a change to a status flag, that's fine.

The currently registered reference for PATCH is RFC 5789

The server MUST apply the entire set of changes atomically and never    provide (e.g., in response to a GET during this operation) a partially modified representation.  If the entire patch document cannot be successfully applied, then the server MUST NOT apply any of the changes.

So you need to think a little bit carefully about how you "apply the patch" to the representation of the resource.
Very roughly, the semantics of PATCH are essentially those we would want for remote authoring of a raw "document".  For example, we might fix a spelling error on a web page by sending a patch document to the web server, and the server's implementation would be expected to apply the entire patch or none of it.
REST's uniform interface constraint says that those semantics should be the same no matter what the underlying implementation of the resource.
So if your implementation cannot satisfy the atomicity constraint of PATCH, you must either (a) accept that your implementation is responsible for any loss of property that results, or (b) remove PATCH from the list of supported methods for that resource.

A perfectly valid alternative to sending a PATCH request is to send a POST request:
POST /api/order/12345
Content-Type: text/plain

Bob,
Please change the order_status to "Built"

From a REST/HTTP perspective, this is fine.  It's likely that you have to do more work in your implementation (to distinguish this POST from the other POST request messages targeting the same resource).
Sending a POST request to the primary resource changed by successful handling of the request allows you to leverage the general purpose cache invalidation that is built into HTTP.
Creating a separate resource for that work is fine
POST /api/order/12345/build
Content-Type: text/plain

Bob,
Do it.

That'll work; it's just not quite as cache friendly as the previous alternative.  Welcome to the world of trade offs.


Or should my patch handle the updating of the status and an additional API call made to perform the remaining actions?

I'd only do this if the extra ceremony made things significantly better for some humans that you care about (your customers, your operations team, your documentation team, whatever).
Adding ceremony to satisfy contrived constraints is waste.

It's certainly OK for a property change to result in side-effects for non-safe methods like PATCH, and this is probably the reasonable thing to do. Business logic should be mostly owned by the server, so relying on a client to make another request doesn't seem to serve a purpose.
However, using POST to kick off some process is also fine.
